# Excel VBA Out of Memory Error on If Statement

Tags: vba, excel, memory

I'm trying to figure out a problem in Excel.  I am getting an Out of Memory error and I suspect that's not the problem but I don't really know.

Basically, I'm trying to make a macro that searches for a column within 5 tabs in a spreadsheet (the column can be in any of the 5 and it changes a lot) and when it finds it, does a vlookup match to return the column to the appropriate place in the master tab.  Here is my code below which seems like it should work but I get the Out of Memory error. the line that is highlighted when I go to debug is the first `Vrange = rB` line in the if statement.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim r As Range
'
Dim wsMaster As Worksheet: Set wsMaster = Workbooks("LBImportMacroTemplate.xlsm").Worksheets("MasterTab")
Dim wsB As Worksheet: Set wsB = Workbooks("LBImportMacroTemplate.xlsm").Worksheets("B")
Dim wsE As Worksheet: Set wsE = Workbooks("LBImportMacroTemplate.xlsm").Worksheets("E")
Dim wsL As Worksheet: Set wsL = Workbooks("LBImportMacroTemplate.xlsm").Worksheets("L")
Dim wsI As Worksheet: Set wsI = Workbooks("LBImportMacroTemplate.xlsm").Worksheets("I")
Dim wsT As Worksheet: Set wsT = Workbooks("LBImportMacroTemplate.xlsm").Worksheets("T")
'
Dim rBHeading As Range: Set rBHeading = wsB.Range("A2:ZA2")
Dim rEHeading As Range: Set rEHeading = wsE.Range("A2:ZA2")
Dim rLHeading As Range: Set rLHeading = wsL.Range("A2:ZA2")
Dim rIHeading As Range: Set rIHeading = wsI.Range("A2:ZA2")
Dim rTHeading As Range: Set rTHeading = wsT.Range("A2:ZA2")
'
Dim rB As Range: Set rB = wsB.Range("A:ZA")
Dim rE As Range: Set rE = wsE.Range("A:ZA")
Dim rL As Range: Set rL = wsL.Range("A:ZA")
Dim rI As Range: Set rI = wsI.Range("A:ZA")
Dim rT As Range: Set rT = wsT.Range("A:ZA")
'
Dim mf_iA_TEXT As String: mf_iA_TEXT = "iA"
'
If Application.CountIf(rBHeading, "iA") = 1 Then
    Vrange = rB
    Mrange = rBHeading
ElseIf Application.CountIf(rEHeading, "iA") = 1 Then
    Vrange = rE
    Mrange = rEHeading
ElseIf Application.CountIf(rLHeading, "iA") = 1 Then
    Vrange = rL
    Mrange = rLHeading
ElseIf Application.CountIf(rIHeading, "iA") = 1 Then
    Vrange = rI
    Mrange = rIHeading
Else
    Vrange = rT
    Mrange = rTHeading
End If
'
Dim mf_iA As Variant: mf_iA = Application.Match(mf_iA_TEXT, Mrange, 0)
'
With ActiveSheet
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    MsgBox lastrow
End With
'
For i = 2 To lastrow
    wsMaster.Cells(i, 2) = Application.VLookup(wsMaster.Cells(i, 1), Vrange, mf_iA, 0)
Next i
'
End Sub
```

I also tried to accomplish this with a case statement but I felt like I got further with the above code.  If you could please let me know if this code is dumb, or if I can solve the Out of Memory error, I would greatly appreciate it.  If I can get this to work, I will be copying the process with many many more columns, in case that matters.  Thanks!!

Comment: If you haven't dimmed `Vrange`, then Excel will treat it as a `Variant` and attempt to load the entire contents of your range `rB` (which was defined as `Set rB = wsB.Range("A:ZA")`) as an array to this new variable `Vrange`.  Because the array would be 27 columns and over 65000 (or over 1 million on Excel 2007+) rows, Excel crashes.  Basically you need to declare Vrange as a range variable with the line `Dim Vrange as Range` and then `Set` it to be the desired range in your If.. Elseif.. statement.

Comment: Looks like you'd also need to do the same for `Mrange`

Comment: oh man, I think that did it!! that's good information to have, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you started, the first 56 lines of code could be written as,

```
    Dim v As Long, vWSs As Variant, Mrange As Range, Vrange As Range, mf_iA as long
    Dim wsMaster As Worksheet: Set wsMaster = Workbooks("LBImportMacroTemplate.xlsm").Worksheets("MasterTab")
    Dim mf_iA_TEXT As String: mf_iA_TEXT = "iA"

    vWSs = Array("B", "E", "L", "I", "T")
    With Workbooks("LBImportMacroTemplate.xlsm")
        mf_iA = 0: Set Mrange = Nothing: Set Vrange = Nothing
        For v = LBound(vWSs) To UBound(vWSs)
            If CBool(Application.CountIf(.Sheets(vWSs(v)).Range("A2:ZA2"), mf_iA_TEXT)) Then
                Set Mrange = .Sheets(vWSs(v)).Range("A2:ZA2")
                Set Vrange = .Sheets(vWSs(v)).Range("A:ZA")
                ' added the column number assignment on the next line
                mf_iA = application.match(mf_iA_TEXT, Mrange, 0)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next v
    End With

    if mf_iA = 0 then msgbox "Stop here! " & mf_iA_TEXT & "not found!"
    'assumed that Mrange and Vrange are not nothing at this point
    ' and that mf_iA is the numerical column index number for mf_iA_TEXT
    'do something with them


    Set Mrange = Nothing
    Set Vrange = Nothing
    Set wsMaster = Nothing
```

That takes you to the end of the `If/ElseIf/End If` where you can continue processing. The last three are just reminders to manually set the ranges and workbook object to nothing after you are done with them.

Comment: Thank you, I like what you've done here and I didn't know about Lbound/Ubound/Cbool, so thanks.  But I have put the match and vlookup down in your commented part, and I get an error: `Invalid Procedure Call or Argument`.  It looks exactly like how I wrote it in the original question (the part after my IF statement)

Comment: @msim - Your `mf_iA` was never assigned a numerical value. If it is intended to represent the column number that `mf_iA_TEXT ` appears, I've made an adjustment within the `For ... Next` loop to assign it.

Comment: that looks like it worked.  One more thing if you have time, if I were to repeat this with a lot more columns, would I just copy from the FOR loop down and change out the necessary variables?  Because I tried that and it stops me on the `countIf(.Sheets...` saying `invalid or unqualified reference`, and i don't get why it would work on the first column but get stuck on the next one.

Comment: @msim - You should be able to change (or substitute for another var) `mf_iA_TEXT` and `mf_iA` for subsequent retrievals. If you have rewritten the bulk of your code using the methods above, consider posting a new question showing the new code and how you are attempting additional column retrievals. The first question that will be asked if if `mf_iA_TEXT` is found, will subsequent columns to be retrieved be guaranteed to be found or could they be from another worksheet.

Comment: again thank you.  I figured out what was wrong (too many `End With`s) but now I have a different problem, and I made a new question for it.  Thanks.